# AWS SES Managing and Forwarding Incoming Mail

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, email-server, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

I'm probably in over my head with this one. Please bare with me while i fumble through my explanation of what it is that i am trying to accomplish here.

We own a domain name. Have access to the back end. It's hosted digitalocean. Its blank, has no end user interface, or any other editing done to it other than a few things SES requires for validation, which i will get into shortly.

What i am trying to accomplish is I'd like to use my domain to create custom email addresses for my group, and have it auto-forward to their respective personal accounts.

I have gone through the initial setup and song and dance Amazon requires you to complete to get out of sandbox mode. I have also verified my domain in the SES control panel by editing the DNS stuff to show the proper CNAMEs, Keys, MX Records and so on. All that stuff comes back clean and verified.

I have also set up an S3 Bucket for the mail, created policies include the bucket, AWS Server region and my account ID in the code.

Lastly there is the Lambda code. I am no expert in Python. So i found an example code in the AWS SES tutorials and support section and used that while supplementing in my variables where needed (bucket name, region, mail recipient, ect)

Im beginning to think what i am trying to do is not possible, or i am going about it incorrectly.

TL;DR: I have a blank domain verified with SES that i want to send email to but have it forwarded to my gmail with AWS SES. How do?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Trying to set up @mydomain.com email addresses through SES and have them autoforward to specified gmail/outlook/anything i point it to. The mail is undeliverable at this time. I get the following sent to the recipient address that should be getting forwarded emails 24hrs after i send a test message:

Comment: DNS Error: 2410809 DNS type 'mx' lookup of MYDOMAIN.COM responded with code NOERROR 2410809 DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of inbound-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. responded with code NOERROR 2410809 DNS type 'aaaa' lookup of inbound-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. had no relevant answers. 2410809 DNS type 'a' lookup of inbound-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. responded with code NOERROR 2410809 DNS type 'a' lookup of inbound-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com. had no relevant answers.